# Maintain right handedness of a rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, reflection

I have a rotation matrix represented by $$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    xx & xy & xz \\
    yx & yy & yy \\
    zx & zy & zz \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$
which is also an orthogonal matrix (determinant is **+1**). After reflecting about XY plane by using the matrix  $$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$ the determinant of the resultant matrix will be **-1**. What changes can I make to the resultant matrix so that the determinant becomes **+1**?

Below is an image for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOb7J.png)

[image]

I tried flipping one of the vectors, but that is changing the orientation of the part in CATIA. so it's a no go.

e.g.
Matrix before reflection:
$$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.16 & 0 & 0.99 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -0.99 & 0 & 0.16\\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$
Matrix after reflection about XY plane:
$$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.16 & 0 & -0.99 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    -0.99 & 0 & -0.16\\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$
Both matrices have determinant **+1**

Comment: You can multiply by diag(1,1,-1) again.

Comment: @NicNic8 I tried by multiplying the matrix with diag(1,1-1), but the determinant value I got is -0.95.

Comment: Let the rotation matrix be R.  By reflecting, I assume that you mean you did the following:  R' = diag(1,1,-1) R.  Is this the case?  If so, left multiply again by diag(1,1,-1).  Then R'' = diag(1,1,-1) diag(1,1,-1) R.  Since diag(1,1,-1) diag(1,1,-1) = I, R'' = R.  It all works if you right multiply instead.

Comment: @NicNic8 you are correct, I was multiplying wrong. But after following your method I got the original matrix back, which is not the expected output. I have updated the post with image and matrices. Please have a look

Comment: Welcome! Here's an analogy: I took a positive number and negated it. What can I do to make it non-negative? Well...there are several answers: you could raise it up to $0$. You could set it to $17$. You could re-negate it and get back the original positive number. The same thing holds for your matrix: there are infinitely many answers to your question, and we need to know some additional constraints to give you an answer that's useful. (Or, perhaps, you need to rethink your question -- it may be that it has no answer because of fundamental properties of determinants and orientations.)

Comment: The fourth matrix you posted isn't the product of the reflection (the second matrix) and the third matrix. The -1 on the diagonal should be +1. The fourth matrix would be the product of the third and diag(1,-1,-1) which is a rotation (which is equiv to two reflections).